# node-gyp build from different directory

Tags: node-gyp

whenever i do

```
 node-gyp build
```

i need to be in the directory that has my binding.gyp 'build' directory.

I was wondering if there is a way where my current working directory could be somewhere else and I could specify the path to build at.

My use case is I spend most of my time in the working directory ~, where i like stop/start/restart node and i dont really want to 'cd' to 'api/v1/C' (which is where I keep my .c files) every time i want to build them.

(i suppose i could just write a script that does 'cd' to my 'api/v1/C', runs node-gyp build, then 'cd ~', however i'd like to know if there is another way without making a script)

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp#command-options):

```
-C $dir, --directory=$dir   Run command in different directory
```